# SQL Query syntax in Laravel Controller

Tags: sql, laravel

The following code is trying to update a column itself by multiplying by an input variable:

```
$multiplier = $request->input("disc");

DB::statement('SET entries UPDATE dp = dp * :multiplier', array('multiplier' => $multiplier));
```

When I run this I get an error regarding my syntax.

I used https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries to try and create my query.

Comment: Not an sql expert, but have you tried without `SET entries`? What is this supposed to do?

Comment: "I get an error" - which is? Please always include full quotes of errors in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query syntax is wrong, please check for the correct (assuming it is mysql) [one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

```
$multiplier = $request->input("disc");

DB::statement('UPDATE entries SET dp = dp * :multiplier', ['multiplier' => $multiplier]);
```